# algorithm that print specific num of indexes in for loop using c

Tags: c, for-loop

I have three variables `T`, `n` and `m`, where `T` is a long double, `n` and `m` are integers and `n` is divisable by `m`.

I have to pass all the numbers from 0 to `T` with `n` steps

```
for (long double i = 0; i < someNum; i += T/n) {...}
```

In my for-loop, I have to print `m` times `i`. If I have `n` steps, then I would need to print every time `i % (n / m) == 0`.

How can I do that inside my for-loop?

Comment: don't use floating point as loop indices, and for modulo...

Comment: ok, is there another way to solve my problem. because T can be long double so what can i do

Comment: cast the `long double j` to `long long i` and then try in loop  `for ( i = 0; i < someNum && i % (n / m) == 0 ; i += T/n) {...}`

Comment: but long long can not represent 64464.05540484515 for example

Comment: you cannot run a loop `4.52` time or something like this.

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking for.  Do you have one loop or two nested loops?  Do you need `n` or `n+1` steps between `0.0` and `T`?  What do you need to do with `m`?  You say you need to 'print `m` times `i`'; do you simply mean `m * i`?  Your code shows you dividing by `m`, not multiplying — one of the sources of confusion.  Given that `n` is divisible by `m`, then `(n / m)` is an integer with no remainder, which could well be useful when we know what the output should be.  Show some example control values (simple ones) and the expected output.

Comment: i have one loop and i need `n + 1` steps. i need to print m times i but not `m * i` times I need to print ' i ' every time 'i % floor(n / m) == 0' .

Comment: an simple example: if T = 100, and n = 10 and m = 2; the output is (0, 5) ............... another example: if T = 100, and n = 100 and m = 50; the output is (0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, ........, 98) .......... another example: if T = 100, and n = 10 and m = 5; the output is (0, 20, 40, 60, 80)

Comment: @MohammadJaber In the first example, how can `i` be ever `5` when `i += T/n` is done and `T/n` is `10`? And in the third example, why isn't `10` included when `i` is being incremented by `10` and `n/m` is `2`? `10%2` is `0`, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best to avoid using floating point math in computing indexes in a `for()` loop.  [@Jean-François Fabre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46635232/algorithm-that-print-specific-num-of-indexes-in-for-loop-using-c/46692502#comment80219693_46635232).  The following uses only integers and integer math for the `for` loop header calculations.

`%` or mod-ding of integers or floating-point values is not needed in the `for()` block.  An "epsilon" calculation is not needed.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void pathC(long double totalTime, int stepsNum, int stepsToSave) {
  // n is divisible by m.
  assert(stepsNum % stepsNum == 0);

  int dStep = stepsNum / stepsToSave;
  for (int i = 0; i < stepsNum; i += dStep) {  // integer indexing
    printf("%.0Lf, ", totalTime * i / stepsNum);
  }
  puts("");
}

int main(void) {
  pathC(100, 10, 2);
  pathC(100, 100, 50);
  pathC(100, 10, 5);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
0, 50, 
0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, ... 94, 96, 98, 
0, 20, 40, 60, 80,
```

The first differs from [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46635232/algorithm-that-print-specific-num-of-indexes-in-for-loop-using-c/46692502#comment80241721_46635232) of " if T = 100, and n = 10 and m = 2; the output is (0, 5)", yet that is certainly a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You can't be using the `%` operator for `float` operands. The operands of `%` should be of type `int`.

Use `fmodl()` instead. It takes 2 parameters of type `long double` and return a `long double`. It performs the floating point equivalent of the `%` operator.
`fmod()` is for `double` and `fmodf()` for `float`. Read about them [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/fmod).

They are in `math.h` header file.

If you *must* use `long double` type for `i`, do something like

```
long double T=100, i;
int n=100, m=50;

for(i=0; i<n; i+=T/n)
{
    if( fmodl(i, n/m)==0 )
    {
        printf("%Lf\n", i);
    }
}
```

If `i` was an integer, `%` operator can be used instead of `fmodl()`.

Comment: @MohammadJaber Can you give the output and expected output along with the values of other variables?

Comment: i solve the problem and i will wrote my algorithm as an Answer ... thanks you all.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define epsilon pow(10, -5)

bool modFunc (long double x , long double y) {
        while (x > epsilon) {
            x -= y;
        }
        if (x >= -epsilon && x <= epsilon) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

void path(long double totalTime, int stepsNum, int stepsToSave) {
        long double dt = totalTime / stepsNum;
        for (long double i = 0; i < (totalTime - epsilon); i += dt) {
            bool mod = modFunc(i, (totalTime / stepsToSave));
            if (mod == true) {
                printf("%0.3Le,", i);
            }
        }
    }
```

i wrote my own mod method and that work with me....

Comment: This fails to meets OP's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46635232/algorithm-that-print-specific-num-of-indexes-in-for-loop-using-c/46692502#comment80241721_46635232) "if T = 100, and n = 10 and m = 2; the output is (0, 5)"

Comment: the output is (0, 50) not (0, 5) i wrote that wrong